# Recurring tasks in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 alternatives for executing recurring tasks in ASP.NET MVC.

We just need to add some code in Global.asax

First alternative:

```
private static void ThreadSendNextMail()
{
  while (true)
  {
    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async cancellationToken =>
    {
      using (var db = new EFDbContext())
      {
        try
        {
          //demo test for periodically tasks
          int paymentCount = await db.Payments.AsNoTracking().CountAsync();
          logger.Info(paymentCount);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          logger.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
      }
    });
    Thread.Sleep(20000);
  }
}
  
private Thread mailThread { get; set; }
  
protected void Application_Start()
{
  //other code removed for clarity
  mailThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadSendNextMail));
  mailThread.Start();
}
```

Second alternative:

```
private void AddTask(Action<string, object, CacheItemRemovedReason> target, int seconds)
{
  HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(target.Method.Name + DateTime.Now.ToString(), seconds, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(target));
}
  
public void SendNextMail(string key, object seconds, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
{
  HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async cancellationToken =>
  {
    using (var db = new EFDbContext())
    {
      try
      {
        //demo test for periodically tasks
        int paymentCount = await db.Payments.AsNoTracking().CountAsync();
        logger.Info(paymentCount);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        logger.Error(ex.ToString());
      }
    }
  });
    
  AddTask(SendNextMail, Convert.ToInt32(seconds));
}
  
protected void Application_Start()
{
  //other code removed for clarity
  
  //Periodically tasks
  AddTask(SendNextMail, 20);
}
```

I use .NET 4.5.2 and MVC 5.2. For logging I use NLog.

Both methods work perfectly (you can check this by watch log time in log file). Which is more preferable and better for performance, if I have many recurring tasks in the same time?

Do you see any improvement / issue?

Comment: The first will block a thread for 20 seconds, never ever do that

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned by `Anders`, the second approach is better, however there are several problems when implementing async Tasks that run within an `IIS` worker process:

**1) unhandled exceptions** in the async threads/tasks kill the entire process. This should not be a problem in your code, since you catch all exceptions and normally, `NLog` handle does not have unhandled exception.

**2) worker process may suddenly stop** for various reasons such as `web.config`, `binaries`, `idle recycling` and the task might be stopped in the middle of its work. This should not happen in your case, since the operation seems pretty short and ASP.NET will [try to delay the shutdown of the process](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) to allow background workers to finish their jobs.

I also remark the possible optimization brought by [using an Async function along with await on the same instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640371/await-and-async-in-same-line).

A small improvement is to use `UnitOfWork` pattern for your database context, but the benefit comes when more complex things happen in your worker:

```
/// <summary>
/// unit of work store
/// </summary>
public static class UnitOfWorkStore
{
    public static object GetData(string key)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            return HttpContext.Current.Items[key];
        return CallContext.GetData(key);
    }

    public static void SetData(string key, object data)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            HttpContext.Current.Items[key] = data;
        else
            CallContext.SetData(key, data);
    }
}

public partial class EFDbContext
{
    #region Members
    private static readonly object objSync = new object();
    private static readonly string DATACONTEXT_KEY = "EFDbContext_UserInstance";
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Uses a UnitOfWorkStore to return the same instance of Context, that is unique
    /// per user, per postback (or CallContext, if not in an HttpContext environment, such as unit tests or console apps)
    /// </summary>
    public static EFDbContext Instance
    {
        get
        {
            // Dirty (non thread-safe) check
            if (UnitOfWorkStore.GetData(DATACONTEXT_KEY) == null)
            {
                lock (objSync)
                {
                    // Thread-safe check
                    if (UnitOfWorkStore.GetData(DATACONTEXT_KEY) == null)
                    {
                        var context = new EFDbContext();
                        UnitOfWorkStore.SetData(DATACONTEXT_KEY, context);
                    }
                }
            }
            return (EFDbContext)UnitOfWorkStore.GetData(DATACONTEXT_KEY);
        }
    }
}
```

So, that generating a new context can be done using EFDbContext.Instance and unit of work pattern will take care to return the same instance if called in the same "context". Also, it looks like [database context disposal is not really necessary](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html#.U6WdzrGEeTw).

**[later edit]**

Just remembered a couple of things:

**3) `AsNoTracking()`** is a good option when fetching read-only data. It is faster and allocates less memory, so its usage is welcomed (however, I rarely see it used).

**4) Idle timeout** - by default, IIS will stop the application pool if it has not activity. This means that no processing will be made during some periods (e.g. during week-ends)